# Android studio cant find my specific binding

Tags: kotlin

Im trying to implement databinding into my app. For some reason, android studio finds a generic "viewdatabinding" instead of my ActivityMainBinding.

this is my mainactivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(this, R.layout.activity_main)



}
```

}

this is my activity_main.xml

```
 <Layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigationFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </Layout>
```

and this is my gradle build file

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.gintastic"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding{
        enabled = true

    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}
```

the error im getting is the following:
[image]

Ive done this before for an other project and had no trouble doing so. Maybe its because its a different SDK version?

Answer (score 0):

It is simple, you are not generating DataBinding class at all.
DataBinding xml should look like:

```
layout tag 
 -data tag
 -other xml
close layout tag
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i typed Layout instead of layout.
my bad